# How can I use annotations to represent a parameterized type?

Tags: java, annotations

I trying to using annotation processor to generate some methods like that:

```
void result(Consumer<Type> name){

}
```

Than I need to using a annotation to represent a parameter.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface Parameter {

  String name();

  Class<?> type();
}
```

But the annotation members only support compile-time constants, so it is impossible to delivery a parameterized type directly, for example the following illegal java code can't be represent by annotation.

```
@Parameter(name ="ids",type = ArrayList<Integer>.class)
```

I tried to declare a new annotation to represent the type, because the generic parameters can be one or more and nested, such as `ArrayList <HashMap <String, String >>`, but java does not support annotations reference itself, it will cause **cyclic annotation element type** error. the following annotation is illegal too.

```
public @interface Type{
  Class<?> type();
  Type[] parameters() default {};
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface Parameter {

  String name();

  Type type();
}
```

Any solutions?

Comment: What are you trying to model with this annotation?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I trying to using annotation processor to generate some methods like that: `void result(Consumer<Type> name)`

Comment: Yeah, describe that use case in more detail. It's not immediately obvious why you need it exactly like this. See [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Ok

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis That link that you added to the XY problem should be the header to all questions :)

Answer (score 0):

When you cannot represent a value as an annotation argument, the standard solution is to use a string instead.  For example, instead of `@Parameter(..., type = ArrayList<Integer>.class)`, use `@Parameter(..., type = "ArrayList<Integer>")`, which can represent arbitrarily-nested parameterized types.

Your code that uses the annotations must do parsing and validation of the String argument.